# JTabbedPane aligning components

Tags: java, swing, alignment, jtabbedpane

I have JTabbedPane with a few tabs. The problem i am facing is i have a panel which has 2 buttons inside it and a text area. the panel is inside a JScrollPane. I then add the JScrollPane to the tab, but the buttons and the text area are next to each other and are aligned in the center. What i want is the JTextArea to be under the buttons instead of being to the right of buttons. I have tried using BorderLayout for the buttons and text area (Putting buttons to page start and text area page end), but it doesn't change anything.

```
Panel.add(But1, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
Panel.add(But2, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
Panel.add(TextArea, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
JScrollPane JSPane = new JScrollPane(Panel);
TabbedPanel.addTab("Tab name", JSPane);
```

Comment: [Layout manager tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/). Remember that you can nest JPanels, each using its own layout manager.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue might be with adding two buttons to the BorderLayout.PAGE_START. The second button will override the first button. 
[A Visual Guide to Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html), specifically the BorderLayout example should help.

Comment: @Hovercraft You were much quicker. Sorry for the duplicate entry.

Comment: Im pretty sure its because of the JTabbedPane, because this same layout works fine for me when i simply add it to a frame

Comment: @Minde: I'm pretty sure that you're wrong. Yours is a layout problem pure and simple. If you need more specific help, create and post your [minimal example program](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). 1+

Comment: Yes, i forgot to add new BorderLayout() when i made the panel. so doing JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout()); Fixed it.